# No module named 'gensim' in AWS Glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, gensim, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to use Gensim in AWS Glue ETL job. I have created and tested the gensim wheel in sagemaker and it appears to be working correctly. I have added the wheel file in S3 and added the path in the "Python library path" in glue job details. Still the glue script fails with gensim not found error.

Gensim setup.py file

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="gensim",
    version="4.1.0",
    packages=['gensim'],
    install_requires=['Cython', 'numpy', 'scipy', 'smart-open']
)
```

After creating the wheel file, I tested it and it installed gensim properly.

```
sh-4.2$ pip install dist/gensim-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl 
Processing ./dist/gensim-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython-3.0.0a11-py3.7.egg (from gensim==4.1.0) (3.0.0a11)
Requirement already satisfied: smart-open in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/smart_open-6.2.0-py3.7.egg (from gensim==4.1.0) (6.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gensim==4.1.0) (1.21.6)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gensim==4.1.0) (1.7.3)
Installing collected packages: gensim
Successfully installed gensim-4.1.0
```

Glue job output logs show that it is installed properly

```
2022-09-28T18:33:40.657+05:30   Processing ./glue-python-libs-rutqf0ex/gensim-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl

2022-09-28T18:33:40.730+05:30   Collecting smart-open

2022-09-28T18:33:40.749+05:30   Downloading smart_open-6.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)

2022-09-28T18:33:41.500+05:30   Collecting Cython

2022-09-28T18:33:41.508+05:30   Downloading Cython-0.29.32-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl (2.0 MB)

2022-09-28T18:33:42.216+05:30   Collecting numpy

2022-09-28T18:33:42.221+05:30   Downloading numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.8 MB)

2022-09-28T18:33:43.126+05:30   Collecting scipy

2022-09-28T18:33:43.143+05:30   Downloading scipy-1.5.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.9 MB)

2022-09-28T18:33:44.258+05:30   Installing collected packages: smart-open, Cython, numpy, scipy, gensim

2022-09-28T18:33:49.744+05:30

Copy
Successfully installed Cython-0.29.32 gensim-4.1.0 numpy-1.19.5 scipy-1.5.4 smart-open-6.2.0
Successfully installed Cython-0.29.32 gensim-4.1.0 numpy-1.19.5 scipy-1.5.4 smart-open-6.2.0

2022-09-28T18:33:53.981+05:30   Processing ./glue-python-libs-rutqf0ex/bio-1.3.9-py3-none-any.whl
```

Glue job error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'
```

I came across these two errors in the glue error log.

```
ERROR: botocore 1.12.232 has requirement urllib3<1.26,>=1.20; python_version >= "3.4", but you'll have urllib3 1.26.12 which is incompatible.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 211, in <module>
    runpy.run_path(temp_file_path, run_name='__main__')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/glue-python-scripts-cr7714l4/train-lda-model.py", line 11, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 230, in <module>
    raise e_type(e_value).with_traceback(new_stack)
  File "/tmp/glue-python-scripts-cr7714l4/train-lda-model.py", line 11, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'
```

Comment: tried https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-version2-external-python-libraries/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Since "gensim" is a custom library you need to pack the dependency as a zip file, uploading it to s3 and indicate the s3 path in the Glue job param  called "Python library path". [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html#aws-glue-programming-python-libraries-dev-endpoint)

Comment: Sadly, that did not work for me